# uploading multiple files in cake does not work

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have following form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="file" name="data[MyModel][myfiles]" multiple="multiple">
</form>
```

When I select many files and submit `$this->request->data['MyModel']['myfiles']` contains only last selected file not multiple... `$_FILES` also contains last selected file...

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try change the element name to `data[MyModel][myfiles][]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because file input need to have a proper name attribute. Here is example^

```
<input type="file" name="data[Album][images][]"/>
```

Notice that it have an empty brackets at the end — this is what you need to add at your file input. After subbmiting form your data will have that structure:

```
Array
    (
        [Album] => Array
            (
                [images] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => goldenWS.jpg
                                [type] => image/jpeg
                                [tmp_name] => E:\xampp\tmp\php8EB5.tmp
                                [error] => 0
                                [size] => 1107065
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => ground_floor__please_by_ether-d4c1ru7.jpg
                                [type] => image/jpeg
                                [tmp_name] => E:\xampp\tmp\php8EC6.tmp
                                [error] => 0
                                [size] => 1027305
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

Notice that an empty brackets we placed in the name atribute now populated with an index of a file.

Answer (score 6):

IE does not support multiple file upload, safari also

Use this:

```
echo $form->input('files. ', array(
    'label' => 'Files:',
    'type' => 'file',
    'multiple' => 'multiple',
));
```